# Why is my display getting garbled?

Tags: graphics, display

I recently installed the latest Ubuntu version 12.10 on my USB stick and booted my laptop with it. The OS runs just fine and as expected but there are a few niggles though! Sometimes when I start a program or open a folder, suddenly the screen gets all garbled for a while. It returns to normal when I take a screenshot of it or whenever I simply refresh the screen.

Would appreciate if someone could tell me why this is happenning on an almost regular basis. If I can get over this issue then I'll surely not mind installing the OS on my computer. I've been a Windows user all my life and now I would love to explore the world of Linux as well.

Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: Please share more about your hardware and the kernel drivers in use at the moment. Post the output of `sudo lshw -C video` (you might install `lshw` first) to start with. Also, have you installed all available system updates? Is it a persistent USB installation?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I am such a noob, I don't even know hot to get to the command line prompt. I guess I'll learn along the way!

I've now installed Ubuntu now on my Hard disk using the Wubi installer. It worked just fine the first time I rebooted and I did even get to the main screen and browsing etc. was fine. The next time I booted though, I get a blank screen and then an error of Low graphics mode. There r tons of answers on the net and its confusing, to b honest!
Could u pl guide me to the correct method to solve this issue!
Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce 130M

Comment: I am still getting the issue with the garbled screen. I've installed all the latest updates. Have attached a screenshot of 'sudo lshw -C video'

[link] http://i47.tinypic.com/2cr9gd2.png

@gertvdijk

Comment: Next time copy/paste the output of this. A screenshot is not a convenient way to share text.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `nouveau` driver from the output of the `lshw` command. You should have more luck (and performance) with the closed-source Nvidia driver.

Try to install it using the "Hardware drivers" system application. It should offer you to install this "Additional driver". In my experience the Nouveau driver is "okay", but has many flaws and bugs.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

Comment: Thank you very much for your support @gertvdijk

I think this problem has been solved, for now! Something what's still bugging me though is the speed of the OS. I was under the assumption that Linux will be just as fast, if not faster, than my Win 7 OS. But Ubuntu is painfully slow. Programs take ages to run and multitasking is painful. Is it due to the 'Wubi' install I did?

Sys details: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6500 @ 2.10GHz × 2
Memory: 3.9 GiB

Comment: @KiranbabuNair I can't tell for sure, but Wubi is certainly a factor in this. Nice for trying out Ubuntu, but not nice for daily use in my opinion.